# Android アプリの権限の画面を表示する方法

Tags: java, android

添付した画像の画面を表示する方法を教えてください。

権限は、ダイアログを表示して許可を求める方法は、検索すると見つかるのですが。
ダイアログの表示ではなく、アプリ情報の権限から表示される、添付画像の画面を表示したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: これはBluetoothのシステム設定の表示についての質問ですが、カメラにも応用出来る可能性があります。[Show only bluetooth system settings activity and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147463/show-only-bluetooth-system-settings-activity-and-nothing-else)

Answer (score -2):

このサイトが参考になれば幸いです
google play ヘルプ　Android スマートフォンでアプリの権限を変更する
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9431959?hl=ja&adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=63E262E21DAE45A094D91AA18548457A
「カメラへのアクセス権限編集アンドロイド」で調べたら出てきました

あとはこちらで試してみたので何とも言えませんが
設定→アプリ→権限
で行けると思われます

Comment: こちらの回答は「スマートフォンの操作方法」のようですが、質問で求めているのは恐らく「(自作の) アプリから権限設定の画面を呼び出す」方法かと思います。